# Retorno nulo de um objeto JS no rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Produtos</h1>

<table class="table table-hover custom" id="tabelaProduto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preco</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= produto.id %></td>
        <td><%= produto.nome %></td>
        <td><%= produto.preco %></td>
        <td data-jtable><%= produto.descricao %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', produto %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_produto_path(produto) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', produto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="botaosomar" value="OK" onclick="vamosSomar()" />

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Produto', new_produto_path %>
```

e o javascript dessa view contida em app/assets/javascripts:

```
var tabela = document.getElementById("tabelaProduto"); console.log(tabela.firstElementChild);
```

Não sei porque raios está retornando nulo nesse objeto :\

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o motivo... era o que eu suspeitava: O JS estava sendo carregado antes da renderizaçao do HTML, dai o ID da tabela que eu estava usando como parametro para atribui-lo a uma variável, não "existia" no ato daquela atribuição.

eu reformatei o código da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tabela = document.getElementById("tabelaProduto");
    console.log(tabela.firstElementChild);
});
```

funcionou ! Obrigado pela atenção de todos.
A dúvida de um pode ser a dúvida de outro.